# angular error when creating new project Data path "" should have required property 'version'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Just installed angular 7.02 and get this when trying to create with:

```
ng new test-e
```

> Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"test-e"}
>   Errors:
>
> Data path "" should have required property 'version'.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is there literally a colon, `:`, in the name of the app?

Comment: If you are referring to ...test-e: then NO; the command was ng new test-e

Answer (score 3):

my life was hell due to this problem the most simple way to get away from this is

```
npm i @schematics/angular@latest --save-dev
```

if you give --version="your ng version" it will create a lot of dependency issues that's why use the above-mentioned code

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 1):

referring to https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/11614/Angular-CLI-Generate-Component-Error
we should use --project which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was also facing the same issue. Resolved this by going to `C:/Users/<username>` and deleting the **node_modules** package from there. Check if there is any redundant node_modules folder and delete that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue after i have messed up with my package-lock.json file due to commit issues, then when I run,

```
npm audit fix
```

my problem was solved and able to run the ng g c commands